Выбор пользователей в select menu
class SelectUser(discord.ui.UserSelect):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            placeholder="Выберите пользователя",
            min_values=1,
            max_values=1,
        )

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Письмо отправлено!", ephemeral=True)

Вот такой код выходит с ошибкой:
AttributeError: module 'discord.ui' has no attribute 'UserSelect'

Как это исправть?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

каких уточнений? я предоставил код и ошибку чтобы мне помогли исправить ее

AttributeError: module 'discord.ui' has no attribute 'UserSelect', указывает на то, что класс UserSelect недоступен в модуле discord.ui. Это, вероятно, означает, что библиотека discord.py не имеет класса с именем UserSelect.

Код работает верно и без ошибок.
Проверьте точно ли Вы импортировали саму библиотеку:
import discord

Проверьте установлена ли самая последняя версия discord.py:
pip install -U discord.py


не работает, может я не использую импорт?

ну, если так, то вставьте import discord в самое начало кода.
